# SOAP wsdl request with annidate complex types

Tags: xml, soap, wsdl, xml-namespaces

I'm trying doing a SOAP request using several object types.
Envelope part contains these information

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
  xmlns:mes="mesdefinition"
  xmlns:dat="datdefinition">
```

In my case, my method GetMembers puts in two parameters named as:
*Paging

MembersFilter*
which are defined as

```
<xsd:element xmlns:q1="datdefinition" minOccurs="0" name="MembersFilter"
nillable="true" type="q1:ArrayMemberSvFilter"/>
<xsd:element xmlns:q2="mesdefinition" minOccurs="0" name="Paging" 
nillable="true" type="q2:ListPag"/>
```

Defining in the request Paging element is not difficult, it only contains two integer elements:

```
<xsd:complexType name="ListPag">
 <xsd:sequence>
  <xsd:element name="PageIdx" type="xsd:int"/>
  <xsd:element name="PageSz" type="xsd:int"/>
 </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

The problem is the MembersFilter one. Schema contains array definition

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:tns="datdefinition" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="datdefinition">
 <xsd:complexType name="ArrayMemberSvFilter">
  <xsd:sequence>
   <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="MemberSvFilter" nillable="true" type="tns:MemberSvFilter"/>
  </xsd:sequence>
 </xsd:complexType>
```

then MemberSvFilter definition

```
<xsd:complexType name="MemberSvFilter">
 <xsd:complexContent mixed="false">
  <xsd:extension xmlns:q123="mesdefinition" base="q123:APIFilterBase">
   <xsd:sequence/>
  </xsd:extension>
 </xsd:complexContent>
</xsd:complexType>
```

MemberSvFilter has several extensions: the one which is useful in my method is MemIDFilter (which allows retrieving only results referring to the passed ID), defined as

```
<xsd:complexType name="MemIDFilter">
 <xsd:complexContent mixed="false">
  <xsd:extension base="tns:MemberSvFilter">
   <xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:element name="MemID" type="xsd:int"/>
   </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:extension>
 </xsd:complexContent>
</xsd:complexType>
```

How can I structure SOAP body correctly with complex type? I tried in this way

```
<mes:GetMembers>
 <dat:MemIDFilter>1234</dat:MemIDFilter>
 <mes:Paging>
  <mes:PageIdx>0</mes:PageIdx> <!--ok-->
  <mes:PageSz>30</mes:PageSz> <!--ok-->
 </mes:Paging>
</mes:GetMembers>
```

but response gives me the entire array of members, not only result referring to member 1234 as I want.

UPDATE:
I'm using SoapUI for retrieving original XML structure for the request. Here it is:

```
<mes:GetMembers>
     <mes:MembersFilter>
        <dat:MemberSvFilter/>
     </mes:MembersFilter>
     <mes:Paging>
        <mes:PageIdx>?</mes:PageIdx>
        <mes:PageSz>?</mes:PageSz>
     </mes:Paging>
</mes:GetMembers>
```

Comment: So from what I can tell, your building your SOAP XML by hand, which can be done, but it does lead to the sort of questions you have.  I'd suggest importing the WSDL, into Visual Studio (or similar), and look at the XML that it creates.  They cut-out all that SOAP junk, and just tweak the XML with an XML parser.  Remember, you'll also run into issues to HTTP headers that most services require (content-length).  SOAP is a bummer, you have my condolences...

Comment: I'm using SoapUI to inspect auto-generated XML structure, I updated the post

Comment: SOAPUI looks promising (new to me), perhaps you can add in the extra data / records that you need, and then inspect the XML produced.  It's nearly impossible to determine what the XML should look like from the schema (though I'm sure the guys that wrote XSD probably could).